# VS10 Windows Form Desginer Crashed

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

When i open the designer it gives me this error.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

if i ignore the error and try to add an item (I.E. button, label, etc.) it crashes and gives me the same error. I saw some things on how it was the Entity Framework but theres not a way to update that that I've found.

Edit: It wasn't a runtime error or a compile error it only kept the designer from working.

Comment: sounds similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313216/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-windows-version-255-255-255-255-culture-neutr

Comment: yeah i already saw that but there's no clear way to fix it. doesn't matter i just created a whole new project copied the code and now it works