# Reflecting a WinRT executable from a .Net 4.x App

Tags: c#, reflection, windows-store-apps, .net-assembly

In a console application; If I execute:

```
Assembly.LoadFrom(@"c:\...\MyWinRTApp.exe")
```

I get:

```
System.BadImageFormatException occurred
HResult=-2147024885
Message=Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\_...\MyWinRTApp.exe' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
Source=mscorlib
```

Is there any way around this?

### EDIT 1

In relation to "Vyacheslav Volkov"'s answer below, I now get a step further, thank you. However I now get a different issue.

```
"assembly.GetExportedTypes()"
now throws
"Cannot resolve dependency to Windows Runtime type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Application'. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent Windows Runtime assemblies must be resolved on demand through the ReflectionOnlyNamespaceResolve event."
```

If I try to ReflectionOnlyLoad the referenced assemblies, then I get the error:

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)".
```

This is related to loading winmd references, and explained in the post here: [Could not load file or assembly 'Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313216/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-windows-version-255-255-255-255-culture-neutr).

The full code I'm trying is this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;

var assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(assemblyPath);

/*WindowsRuntimeMetadata.ReflectionOnlyNamespaceResolve += (x, y) =>
    {
        y.NamespaceName ???
        y.ResolvedAssemblies.Add(Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(???));
        return;
    };*/

foreach (var references in assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies())
{
    try
    {
        Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(references.FullName);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        var fi = new FileInfo(assemblyPath);
        var fi2Name = String.Format("{0}\\{1}.dll", fi.DirectoryName, references.Name);
        var fi2 = new FileInfo(fi2Name);

        if (fi2.Exists)
        {
            Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(fi2.FullName);
        }
    }
    catch (FileLoadException)
    {
        // When a winmd assembly is attempted.
    }
}

return assembly;
```

Any more ideas?

Thanks, Jon

### Edit 2

The latest idea successfully resolves "{Windows.UI.Xaml, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime}".

However, when ".GetExportedTypes()" is called on the "Client.exe" assembly, the 'ReflectionOnlyNamespaceResolve' event is only fired once for namespace "Windows.UI.Xaml", which resolves to "C:\windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.UI.Xaml.winmd".

An exception is then thrown within ".GetExportedTypes()", which is "Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.".

Comment: What do you want to do with this assembly?

Comment: Reflect over it to discover the containing types for display purposes only. I don't need to create a run-time instance of any of the types.

Comment: Still getting: "Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: If you are interested, this is for the open source project 'Docu' (https://github.com/jagregory/docu), allowing it to read Windows Store assemblies. I could ping you the code I'm modifying, and then I could update this question if we make any progress. Thanks, Jon

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I had a similar issue and found that having the .NET 4.5 application pre-load System.Runtime (added a reference include for System.Runtime in the build process for the .NET 4.5 build) allowed 'GetExtractedTypes' to proceed successfully.

Comment: The Demo code supplied by Vyacheslav Volkov did work on a vanilla project but not on my own project. I think its because we have a complex assortment of PCLs and WinRT native libraries which confuse the issue somewhat. For the moment, this is on the back-burner for us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want only to discover the containing types you should use the [Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyload.aspx).

```
Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(@"c:\...\MyWinRTApp.exe")
```

**UPDATE**

Here's the code that works for me:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve += (sender, eventArgs) => Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(eventArgs.Name);
WindowsRuntimeMetadata.ReflectionOnlyNamespaceResolve += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    string path =
        WindowsRuntimeMetadata.ResolveNamespace(eventArgs.NamespaceName, Enumerable.Empty<string>())
            .FirstOrDefault();
    if (path == null) return;

    eventArgs.ResolvedAssemblies.Add(Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(path));
};

Assembly loadFrom = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(@"C:\....\WinRTApp.exe");
Type[] types = loadFrom.GetExportedTypes();
foreach (Type type in types)
{
    Console.WriteLine(type);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. This gets me a step further, but still no luck. Please see my modified question...

Comment: If you are interested, this is for the open source project 'Docu' (https://github.com/jagregory/docu), allowing it to read Windows Store assemblies. I could ping you the code I'm modifying, and then I could update this question if we make any progress. Thanks, Jon

Comment: Still getting: "Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: Strange but it works for me. I wrote the code that I ran from the console application.

Comment: I think this may be because the exe I'm trying to reflect references a second PCL library (targeting Profile78), which is present in the same folder as the main exe. Sorry for not posting that information, I guess that's pretty relevent! In my code, I have to also ReflectionOnlyLoad the DLLs in the same folder as the exe, which is fine until GetExportedTypes is called, and that's where I get the error about System 2.0.5.0... Cheers, Jon

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the error, can you give the code where you try to load the assemblies?

Comment: @VyacheslavVolkov If you're still there, could you please help me? I seem to be having a similar problem, even when I use your solution. I've asked a question [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35261749/4077294)